# ajax form data serialization failed

Tags: php, ajax

I have a HTML with a form in it like this:

```
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="accept-file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="theform">
    Your Photo: <input id="thefile" type="file" name="photo" size="25" />
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitform();"/>
  </form>
</body>

<script>

  function submitform()
  {
    data = $('*').serialize();

    $.post(
      'http://localhost/banksoal/1.0.0/accept-file.php',
      data
    );
  }

</script>

</html>
```

and the .php script like this:

```
        <?php
  //if they DID upload a file...
  if($_FILES['photo']['name'])
  {
    print_r($_FILES['photo']);
    $message = 'default message';

    //if no errors...
    if(!$_FILES['photo']['error'])
    {
      //now is the time to modify the future file name and validate the file
      $new_file_name = 'd:\\' . '--test-- '.basename($_FILES['photo']['name']); //rename file
      if($_FILES['photo']['size'] > (1024000)) //can't be larger than 1 MB
      {
        $valid_file = false;
        $message = 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';
      }
      else
      {
        $valid_file = true;
      }

      //if the file has passed the test
      if($valid_file)
      {
        //move it to where we want it to be
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $new_file_name);
        $message = 'Congratulations!  Your file was accepted.';
      }
    }
    //if there is an error...
    else
    {
      //set that to be the returned message
      $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['photo']['error'];
    }
  }

  var_dump($message);
?>
```

The problem:
in the submitform() function, in the script tag at the line:

```
data = $('*').serialize();
```

why I get empty result?
What is wrong with the code?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried ready scripts for uploading files using ajax?

Comment: @GeoPhoenix, I haven't tried scripts to upload files (like this one: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/).
Help me please, I don't understand this: if the files are arriving in the server before the user submit the form, how can I relate which files belong to which form submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give thsi a try as mentioned here: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  console.log($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
   data = $('*').serialize();
```

to

```
 data = $('theform').serialize();
```

and change this

```
   <form action="accept-file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="theform">
```

to

```
 <form action="accept-file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="theform" name ="theform">
```

Comment: `#theform`, not `theform`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

You cannot upload files using Ajax, if you MUST upload files in an AJAX-like way you can use hidden iframes, set the target attribute equal to the iframe and grab the iframe's content to know whether the request has failed or not

This is what i usually do for this purpose, create a hidden iframe that will be the target to the form, something like this:

```
<iframe name='formTarget' src='#' style='display:none;' onload='processResult(this);'></iframe>
```

and in processResult you can fetch the iframe's content by:

```
$(results).html();
```

This way when the iframe is loaded it will automatically trigger the function to inform the request is complete